# MonoTouch.Dialog: UINavigation Holding UITabBar - Missing Back Button

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

My MonoTouch.Dialog Reflection-generated form is in an UITabBar which is in a UINavigationControl. Works great.

When the user however clicks the list generated from the following:

```
    [RadioSelection ("State"),Caption("State")]
    public int alleged_violator_state_id = 0;
    public IList<string> alleged_violator_state;
```

The list of states that appear is full screen, not part of the UINavigation. This is understandable as the parent of the dialog is a UITabBar.

Is there a way to have the state view have a back button. Right now the user can't get back from the State view. See images below:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it the wrong way.

Never but a tabbarcontroller within a navigationcontroller.

You should create 1 tabbarcontroller and put a navigation controller in it for every tabbaritem.

Answer (score 0):

Should it be:

```
[RadioSelection ("alleged_violator_state"), Caption("Alleged violator state")]
public int alleged_violator_state_id = 0;
public IList<string> alleged_violator_state;
```

Comment: RadioSelection ignores what ever text is in it. The display always shows the IList field name only.